# Unable to edit a string in wordpress theme

Tags: java, php, css, string, wordpress-theming

I am unable to edit a string in wordpress theme. The theme is not in html so finding source code is tough for me.
This is the source code shown via inspect element:

```
<div class="art-lg-text art-code mb-25"> &lt;<i>code</i>&gt; 
 I love <span class="txt-rotate" data-period="2000" data-rotate="[ &quot;coding.&quot;,&quot;Gaming.&quot;,&quot;photo editing.&quot;,&quot;learning.&quot; ]"><span class="wrap">coding</span></span> &lt;/<i>code</i>&gt;</div>
```

I want to remove `&lt;<i>code</i>&gt` and `&lt;/<i>code</i>&gt` which is shown as `<code>`.....`</code>` on my homepage.
Unfortunately, the index.php and home.php just have references. They don't have a whole code for home page that index.html files generally have.
I searched all files in my theme but couldn't find it. I searched the word "***code***" in my theme folder using **string locator plugin** but it gave 2300+ results! I deleted some related **CSS classes** and removed related contents from demo/01/**content.xml**.
Still couldn't get rid of it.
Where could I find & remove `<code>` `</code>` without removing the contents within it.

Comment: look for the other things which are most likely in the code and not in the database, like `art-code`, `txt-rotate`, `data-period`, `data-rotate`, they are most likely right next to what your looking for

Comment: hey @LawrenceCherone I have added typing.js above. Do I need to remove something from it?

Comment: no, you need to find in the theme or plugin that you use